# Can a certain polynomial have all its coefficients in some basis divisible by a prime $p$?

Tags: polynomials, binomial-coefficients

I fix $n\in\mathbf{N}^{*}$ and $n$ elements $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$ in $\mathbf{N}^{*}$. Consider the polynomial $$Q(T)=\prod\limits_{1\leq i \leq n}  \prod\limits_{0\leq j \leq \alpha_i -1} (\alpha_i T + \alpha_i - j)$$ from $\mathbf{Z}[T]$. This polynomial takes obvioulsy integral values on the integers so that a well-known theorem tells us that we can write $Q$ as $\mathbf{Z}$-linear combination of the polynomials ${T \choose k} = \frac{T(T-1)\ldots (T-k+1)}{k!}$ for $k\in\{0,\ldots,d\}$ (so that ${T \choose 0} = 1$) where $d = \sum\limits_{1\leq i \leq n} \alpha_i$ is the degree of $Q$.

**Remark.** Any $\mathbf{Z}$-linear combination of this kind takes integral values on the integers, and in fact any polynomial of $\mathbf{Q}[T]$ taking integral values on the integers has a unique such decomposition, this statement being the aforementioned theorem. For a reference, see the paragraph about the Hilbert-Serre's theorem in Hartshorne's *Algebraic Geometry*.

So let's write $Q(T) = \sum\limits_{1\leq k \leq d} c_k  {T \choose k}$ with the $c_k$'s in $\mathbf{Z}$. A straightforward calculation shows us that if we set $b_k := \frac{c_k}{\alpha_1 ! \ldots \alpha_n !}$ for $k\in\{0,\ldots,d\}$ we have $$b_k = \sum\limits_{0\leq l \leq k} (-1)^{k+l} {k \choose l} \prod\limits_{1\leq i \leq n} {(l+1)\alpha_i \choose \alpha_i}$$ for $k\in\{0,\ldots,d\}$.

My question is the following : can we find a prime $p$ dividing all the $b_k$'s ?

I conjecture/feel that we can't, but cannot prove it. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is $Q(T)$ correctly defined, as this big product? Or is there a sum sign somewhere? For this $Q$, there is always a term $(a_i T + a_i)$ when $j = 0$, so that $Q(T)$ is always divisible by any $a_i$.

Comment: @RobertGreen Thx for the edit, I was about to do it...

Comment: @PedroM. I went too far by talking about values taken by $Q$, I should have sticked only to the $b_k$'s, sorry.

Comment: @EricFlorentNoube np

Comment: You wrote $\binom{\alpha_i}{(l+1)\alpha_i}$ in the definition of $b_k$. Did you mean $\binom{\alpha_i}{l+1}$? Moreover, when $k > n$ we take $\binom{n}{k} = 0$, right?

Comment: @PedroM. I think that the OP mixed up variables in the english binomial coefficient notation... ;-) Just edited.

Comment: Thx Robert, sorry for this silly mistake.

Comment: Is this something related to actions of $\mathscr{D}$-modules in characteristic $p > 0$ ?... Reminds me of calculations I did long time ago for Bernstein-Sato polynomial in char. $p > 0$.